# Dynamic parsing of milliseconds in DateTime.TryParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I was wondering if it is possible to parse milliseconds dynamically?

Currently I have

```
 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Value, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate))
```

but this forces me to always pass 6 milliseconds. How do I allow the parsing to parse 3 milliseconds if passed?

Comment: `FFFFFF`. No, that's not me being angry, that's [how that works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-f-custom-format-specifier-1).

Comment: You mean how to parse 3 digit milliseconds instead of 6 digits ? Have you tried the following `DateTime.TryParseExact(Value, "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an array of allowed formats to [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] allowedFormats = { "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff", "M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff" };
string Value = "2/15/2018 16:58:46.456";
DateTime startDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(Value, allowedFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(Value);
}
```